# Download file directly to FTP server

Tags: perl, ubuntu, wget

I want to download a big file from a normal http-link to an ftp-server (under ubuntu) without storing the file locally (as my local storage is too small).

Do you have any ideas how to do this with wget or a small perl-script? (I don't have sudo-rights on the local machine).

Comment: new user tip: if you find someone's answer helpful, you may want to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take, combining [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Advanced-Usage) and [Net::FTP](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTP) on the commandline.

```
wget -O - http://website.com/hugefile.zip | perl -MNet::FTP -e 'my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("ftp.example.com"); $ftp->login("user", "pass"); $ftp->put(\*STDIN, "hugefile.zip");'
```

---

Of course, you can put it in a file (`ftpupload.pl`) as well and run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("ftp.example.com"); # connect to FTP server
$ftp->login("user", "pass"); # login with your credentials

# Because of the pipe we get the file content on STDIN
# Net::FTP's put is able to handle a pipe as well as a filehandle
$ftp->put(\*STDIN, "hugefile.zip");
```

Run it like this:

```
wget -O - http://website.com/hugefile.zip | perl ftpupload.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

There's - of course - a CPAN module which makes life easy for FTP:

http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=Net%3A%3AFTP

And WWW::Mechanize looks up files, follows links, etc.

With these modules I think you can solve your problem.

Comment: There's no need for Mechanize here if the OP knows where the file is. [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Simple) will suffice. Though I don't think this will work with an overly huge file because it's probably going to be sequential and thus will take up the space of the file somewhere on the local system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/). It is not very known tool, but i think you can use it.

Comment: +1 because this sounds great; the OP probably can't install it though.

Answer (score 0):

Use wget's output-document option

```
wget -O /dev/null http://foo.com/file.uuu
```

From wget's manual page:

```
"-O file
       --output-document=file
           The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be
concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as file, documents will be
printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file 
literally named -.)

       Use of -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead of the 
one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: wget -O file http://foo is
intended to work like wget -O - http://foo > file; file will be truncated immediately, 
and all downloaded content will be written there."
```

However, I can't see what could be the purpose of that